# Delete duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization, benchmarking

## Delete duplicates in an array

1. One of the function use the native method of JS ES6
2. Is there a better method (compatibility and performance) ?

Note: **filter the undefined element in the array**

English is weak and maybe described as inaccurate. ＞﹏＜

Thanks

```js
function delRepeatArray1(arr) {
    console.time();
    var result = Array.from(new Set(arr));
    console.timeEnd();

    return result;
}

function delRepeatArray2(arr) {
    console.time();
    var result = arr.filter(function (em, index, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(em) === index;
    });
    console.timeEnd();

    return result;
}

var arr = ["undefined", "200", 0, -0, 200, undefined, undefined, null, true, null, "true", false, 0, true, 200, false],
    result1 = delRepeatArray1(arr),
    result2 = delRepeatArray2(arr);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Post your expected output please

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick snippet to get you unique value from the provided array:

```js
var arr = ["undefined", "200", 0, -0, 200, undefined, undefined, null, true, null, "true", false, 0, true, 200, false];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(arr, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
});
console.log(uniqueNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/array-filter-unique/13) that compares a few methods for this. The fastest method was on my system is a plain and simple loop.

```
function unique(arr) {
  let out = [];
  const len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i != len; ++i) {
    const obj = arr[i];
    if (out.indexOf(obj) == -1) out.push(obj);
  }
  return out;
}
```

Although, the benchmark shows that using `reduce` is faster on other systems.

```
function unique(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((out, obj) => {
    if (out.indexOf(obj) == -1) out.push(obj);
    return out;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant we simply make it a set?

```
var arr = ["undefined", "200", 0, -0, 200, undefined, undefined, null, true, null, "true", false, 0, true, 200, false];
var filteredarr = arr.filter(Boolean); //filter undefined
var set = new Set(filteredarr); //remove duplicates
console.log(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is using `Set` to filter out the duplicates.
On your small array there is no difference whatsoever, to benchmark your code you should try a larger array (e.g. at least 65k elements). Then you will see that regular loop (yours `delRepeatArray2`) it's much slower compare to `Set` that will basically keep the same time you have with a smaller group of items.

Said that, we're still talking about few milliseconds.

If you want to filter out the `undefined`, it's better you do it *after* you have reduce to the unique values, so you have only one `undefined` in the Set, and can be easily removed:

```
var set = new Set(arr);
set.delete(undefined);
return Array.from(set);
```